# How RestBase wiki handle caching

Tags: rest, api, wikipedia-api

Following the installation of [RestBase](https://github.com/wikimedia/restbase) using standard config, I have a working version of summary API.

The problem that the caching mechanism seems strange to me.
 The piece of code would decide whether to look at a table cache for fast response. But I cannot make it a server-cache depend on some time-constrain (max-age when the cache is written for example). It means that the decision to use cache or not entirely depend on clients.

Can someone explain the workflow of RestBase caching mechanism?

```
 // Inside key.value.js
   getRevision(hyper, req) {
//This one get the header from client request and decide to use cache 
or not depend on the value. Does it mean server caching is non-existent?
        if (mwUtil.isNoCacheRequest(req)) {
            throw new HTTPError({ status: 404 });
        }
//If should use cache, below run
        const rp = req.params;
        const storeReq = {
            uri: new URI([rp.domain, 'sys', 'table', rp.bucket, '']),
            body: {
                table: rp.bucket,
                attributes: {
                    key: rp.key
                },
                limit: 1
            }
        };
        return hyper.get(storeReq).then(returnRevision(req));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cache invalidation is done by the [change propagation service](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Change_propagation), which is triggered on page edits and similar events. Cache control headers are probably set in the [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/) VCL logic. See [here](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/79/Infrastructure_overview_18_January_2016_%28draft%29.png) for a full Wikimedia infrastructure diagram - it is outdated but gives you the generic idea of how things are wired together.

Comment: Mz wikimedia installation is a small one which follow the standard guide and I do not think they use Kafka for change propagation service. Does it mean that RESTBase has no built-in caching invalidation but rely on an other infranstructure?

Comment: Well, invalidation always has to rely on other infrastructure since RESTBase itself has no way of knowing when to invalidate. If you mean expiration, I'm sure it can be configured via middleware, but default behavior is based on how Wikimedia uses it, since it was primarily meant as an internal tool.